# Transposing CopyFromRecordset Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in my Excel VBA that copies data from a table in SQL into Excel.  This data is being inserted horizontally starting on cell C2, but I want it to be inserted vertically on column C.

```
Sheets("Control").Range("C2").CopyFromRecorset rsPubs
```

Where `rsPubs` is my ADO connection.

Basically, I just want this data transposed.  What's an efficient way of doing this?

This is how `rsPubs` is created (the connection works fine as I'm actually getting the data):

```
' Create a recordset object.
Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rsPubs
    ' Assign the Connection object.
    .ActiveConnection = cnPubs
    ' Extract the required records.
    .Open "SELECT * FROM Analytics.dbo.XBodoffFinalAllocation"
    ' Copy the records into cell B3 on Sheet1.
    Sheets("Control").Range("C2").CopyFromRecordset rsPubs
    ' Tidy up
    .Close
End With

cnPubs.Close
Set rsPubs = Nothing
Set cnPubs = Nothing
```

Comment: "rsPubs is my ADO connection." -- Nope, `rsPubs` isn't your connection, it's your recordset. `cnPubs` is your connection.

Comment: Why does the data need to be transposed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot test this currently, but you could:

```
Sheets("Control").Range("C2").CopyFromRecorset rsPubs 'copy your data
Sheets("Control").Range("C2").Copy 'copy the data into clipboard
Sheets("Control").Range("C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, True, True
```

Also you could use the Transpose Worksheetfunction - however, I don't quite see a way right now to do this directly, expect your input data is transposed already.

Here is a nice official example and further informations on this topic: *[How to transfer data from an ADO Recordset to Excel with automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246335/en-us)*

Especially the "using GetRows" section.

This should do:

```
Dim resultset As Variant
Dim result As Variant
resultset = rsPubs.GetRows
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(resultset)
Sheets("Control").Range("C2").Resize(UBound(result, 1), UBound(result, 2)) = result
```

http://www.teachexcel.com/excel-help/excel-how-to.php?i=147811

Comment: I was going to do that if I had no other ideas but the thing is that where the data is being inserted (C2:W2) or wherever the ending column is, I could possibly have data on E2.  So I wanted it to paste as transposed right away. I'm testing the tranpose worksheet function right now and seeing if that works. Otherwise I'll switch some stuff around so I can just copy the values and paste them. Thanks :)

Comment: hmm .. I expected this to be an issue. Would you mind showing how rsPubs is created? there might be a way to do this erlier in the process.

Comment: I tested it and it said "Subscript out of range".  I did change the range from C2 to K2 while I was testing something else out but i don't know if this is why it wouldn't work.

Comment: The last link is broken (*"Error: page not found"*).

Answer (score 1):

Edit 2 in the accepted answer doesn't work for me, but the following does (see http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/513845-copyfromrecordset-transpose.html for my source):

```
Public Sub PlaceTransposedResults(oResults As ADODB.Recordset, rTarget As Range)
Dim vTransposed As Variant

If Not oResults.EOF Then
    vTransposed = oResults.GetRows
    rTarget.Resize(UBound(vTransposed, 1) + 1, UBound(vTransposed, 2) + 1) = vTransposed
End If
End Sub
```

(this assummes that you haven't changed the array base with the `OPTION BASE` and that your version of Excel has `Range.Resize` and that oResults is never nothing)

One tweak on this is to make this a function and return the correctly sized range - useful if you want to resize a named range to cover the result set.

Another likely tweak is that you may want to optionally allow the user to ask for the field names to be added as the in the first column.  I have found nothing better than:

```
Dim ix As Integer
For ix = 0 To oResults.Fields.Count - 1
    rTarget.Offset(ix, 0) = oResults.Fields(ix).Name
Next ix
```

(of course you then have to offset your main results by 1 column in this case).

Comment: Where are you transposing?

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub CopyTransposed(rng As Range, rs As ADODB.Recordset)
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    x = 0
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        For y = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            rng.Offset(y, x).Value = rs.Fields(y).Value
        Next y
        x = x + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple. It uses Excel's built-in transpose. Can be transposed in a single statement. No looping is needed. Tested and validated.

```
Dim vRecs, vRecsX
vRecs = rsPubs.GetRows
vRecsX = Application.Transpose(vRecs)
Sheets("Control").Range("C2").Resize(rsPubs.RecordCount, rsPubs.Fields.Count) = vRecsX
```

This code is copied directly from a working example.

Note, since this is a worksheet function, expect it to work with arrays of size only up to the number of columns on a worksheet. I believe columns-per-sheet varies between different versions of Excel, so it's a safe bet to determine your transpose limit based on your version of Excel.

"In the modern versions of Excel this is column XFD, which is 16,384 columns. In older versions of Excel (2003 and prior) the last column was IV which is 256 columns."
https://officemastery.com/_how-many-rows-and-columns-in-excel/

Comment: "Tested and validated" Please demonstrate that, with sample input and the result, too many SO answers state that and cannot back it up. SO answers should not contain questions.

Comment: @Yunnosch "sample input" - We can assume the input is a valid recordset. This question isn't asking how to create a recordset. It's written with the assumption that the input is a valid recordset. That's a given. It's not part of the question, so the input needn't be part of the answer. "Result" - I've given the code. A question needn't include an attachment with the code. This code is copied directly from a working example.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion is not to use VBA, at all. Microsoft already provided you the facility to import data from a database.

```
Data -> Import External Data
```

It will, then, create a QueryTable inside the sheet where you can just right-click and refresh in a regular basis. Another bonus is that you don't get the nasty macro warning. The QueryTable can be a table, query or stored procedure.

Try it!