# Excel VBA CopyFromRecordset horizontally?

Tags: excel, vba

I couldn't find a way to use the

```
Range("A100").CopyFromRecordset myRecordSet
```

command in a way data will be inserted horizontally in the sheet. The command will insert data vertically... :-\

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Dim oRst as ADODB.Recordset
Dim vArray As Variant
Dim oRange As Range

oRst = Rst_From_Access(sSQL_Select) 'Some function that gets whatever recordset
ReDim vArray(1 To oRst.RecordCount, 1 To oRst.RecordCount)
vArray = oRst.GetRows 'Load recordset into an array
vArray = Array2DTranspose(vArray) 'Transpose the array
Set oRange = oBook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(vArray, 1), UBound(vArray, 2))) 'Wherever you want to paste the array. 
oRange = vArray 'Paste the array
```

The function `Array2DTranspose` was retrieved from the following URL:
http://www.visualbasic.happycodings.com/Applications-VBA/code30.html

```
Function Array2DTranspose(avValues As Variant) As Variant
Dim lThisCol As Long, lThisRow As Long
Dim lUb2 As Long, lLb2 As Long
Dim lUb1 As Long, lLb1 As Long
Dim avTransposed As Variant

If IsArray(avValues) Then
    On Error GoTo ErrFailed
    lUb2 = UBound(avValues, 2)
    lLb2 = LBound(avValues, 2)
    lUb1 = UBound(avValues, 1)
    lLb1 = LBound(avValues, 1)

    ReDim avTransposed(lLb2 To lUb2, lLb1 To lUb1)
    For lThisCol = lLb1 To lUb1
        For lThisRow = lLb2 To lUb2
            avTransposed(lThisRow, lThisCol) = avValues(lThisCol, lThisRow)
        Next
    Next
End If

Array2DTranspose = avTransposed
Exit Function

ErrFailed:
Debug.Print Err.Description
Debug.Assert False
Array2DTranspose = Empty
Exit Function
Resume
End Function
```

Comment: The idea to paste data into an array is working as expected. As for the Array2DTranspose function, it is scrambling the array. I did not investigate any further because this is not a major issue, as the data in the array is already properly ordered. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do a CopyFromRecordSet and then a copy and paste transpose. Look at this question:

[Transposing CopyFromRecordset Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141639/transposing-copyfromrecordset-excel-vba)